# Give a 30 second window to current room and site users to deal with chat flags

Tags: feature-request, flags, chat

Whenever there's a hurr durr chat flag in one of a given network site's chatrooms, every 10k+ user across the network can see and action it.  This is not always ideal, particularly if the offending chat has active mods or 10k users of its own who are present, and who can see context; local users should have first crack at dealing with chat flags.

I propose something like this:

A 30 second window where a flagged message is only visible to those on the current site's chat, possibly even only users in the current room.  If the flag is actioned by local users, it's dealt with and other network users don't even have to see it.  If after 30 seconds the flag hasn't been actioned, then it pushes out to the rest of the network users, who can action it as they see fit.

Good idea?  Bad idea?

Comment: I have 10k and never saw any notice for chat flag except the Tavern where I'm active. So probably it shows only for those who were active in the room in the last X days or so?

Comment: @ShadowWizard network flags don't show up in the Tavern, or any other MSE chat. Different chat server.

Comment: @3ventic oh, I see. Guess I have to sit in a "real" chat for a while to get the feeling then! ;)

Comment: Yes, this is a good idea (and much better than the horrific notion of leaving chat flags in limbo for *five minutes or more*). I should note that implicit in these proposals is the notion that flags *must* be considered seriously by the greater population of chat if a given room is unable to deal with their own problems promptly; no more saying "oh, that's just The Bridge, hive of scum and villainy blah blah blah - ignore!"

Comment: @Shog9 That number is rather arbitrary in my proposal, I didn't even remember putting in a specific delay. I'd make it much shorter as well if I would write the feature request today.